# Caching Contentful content in Node environment

Tags: javascript, caching, contentful

I am a young developer, and I work on the development of a site whose content is stored on Contentful. Currently, each reloading of the page, the javascript will retrieve the content on Contentful via the API.

The content of the site is not likely to change often, so I would like to cache it.

The site is stored on Netlify. [Link](http://romainberger.fr)

So I thought I could recover the content on Contentful on the Node build, store it in a "cache", that the javascript could use when loading the page. And when modifying on Contentful, a webhook would trigger the rebuild on Netlify.

I do not know if my thinking is the right one, thank you for your help and your answers.

Comment: I would suggest checking out a static site generator such as https://www.gatsbyjs.org/

Answer (score 1):

Contentful actually has caching built into its service so you shouldn't need to do anything to get the benefits of caching on your website. Quoting from the Contentful Docs:

> There are no limits enforced on requests that hit our CDN cache, i.e. the request doesn't count towards your rate limit and you can make an unlimited amount of cache hits. For requests that do hit the Contentful Delivery API enforces rate limits of 78 requests per second and 280800 requests per hour by default. Higher rate limits may apply depending on your current plan.

See https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-delivery-api/#/introduction/api-rate-limits for full details

If you want to do additional caching onto of the Contentful API you could utilize a Node library that'll do it for you. Something like [APICache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apicache) would work pretty well in this use case.

If the rebuilding stack when new content is published, rather than rending it on page view, is important to you, I'd encourage you to take a look at static sites. Contentful has some great webhook support that you can use together with Netlify to help rebuild your site anytime an author pushes new content. Check out this tutorial about using Gatsby for more details - https://www.contentful.com/blog/2018/02/28/contentful-gatsby-video-tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be better to cache the pages separately (instead of caching the whole site) and use a cron job to compare the cache of each page (maybe weekly) against the current version. If it is different, regenerate the cache for that page. Also, you might want to manually trigger that, possibly on deploys or in the rare event when there is a change on a given page.

Anyway, before you start to do all this caching stuff you should check whether your site is anywhere near to be overwhelmed by requests. If not, then caching can be postponed to be later, which would be wise, since, in the case your site's nature will change over time and changes will occur often you might need a different cache, or even no cache at all.

Comment: I added the site [link](http://romainberger.fr) for you to understand better. The site contains only one page.

Comment: @KévinFuret the content is so small, that I think it is premature to implement a cache system for it. But assuming that you need a cache, how is it better to implement a server-side cache in your case than not using a cache system at all? What is the concrete performance and/or memory and/or network benefits of a cache system in this moment?